# Firebase - create an email list

Tags: list, email, firebase

Is there a way to create an email list from Firebase Authentication List ?

I have a list of 2000 people and want to create an email list from it , is there anything that I can do to create the same list in Excel or Notepad but with only emails ?

Comment: When a user has authenticated with email, then you must create a user page at realtime database or cloud firestore document to able to store this user's other data(s), because at user object you can not store any data. So, if you created users path at realtime database or user document at users collections. Then you may handle users data individualy or with group. Other way yo handle users at cloud functions platforms as admin check : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users

Answer (score 2):

Look to use the admin SDK to get all the current users. From there you should have access to all the user emails.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users

Comment: Don't forget to allow people to unsubscribe themselves!